# Which Python Versions should I uninstall?

Tags: python, macos

I have apparently installed multipule versions of python and I need to uninstall a few of them .. but I don't know which one(s).

Here are the list of the installed versions:

```
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools-19.2-py2.7.egg
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/readline-6.2.4.1-py2.7-macosx-10.11-x86_64.egg
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy-1.10.2-py2.7-macosx-10.11-x86_64.egg
/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.10_2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python27.zip
/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.10_2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7
/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.10_2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-darwin
/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.10_2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-mac
/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.10_2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-mac/lib-scriptpackages
/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.10_2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-tk
/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.10_2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-old
/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.10_2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages
/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-7.1.2-py2.7.egg
/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages
```

Suggestions?

***Edit**

```
$which python -a
/usr/local/bin/python
```

Looks like only one file popped up.

Comment: Are you sure that you have installed multiple versions?  It looks like these are just resource and library directories for the same installation.  Nothing there suggests multiple versions installed.

Comment: Type `which python -a` to see how many executables are on your path.

Comment: I updated the question with your suggestion, Mike.

Comment: So, looks like there is only one Python on your system.

Comment: Perfect! thanks for showing me this.

Comment: Looks like only one `Python`. You can work with multiple python without any issue using `virtualenv`

Answer (score 1):

While all the paths have th word `Python` in them, they are not different Python installations but rather different parts of one.

```
$which python -a
/usr/local/bin/python
```

This lists all executable with this name. Conclusion: there is only one executable named `python`. No need to uninstall anything.

It is no problem, when different Python versions are installed. Typically, `python3` would use Python 3 and `python` Python 2.

There are several ways to work with multiple Python versions on one system.

1. [virtualenv](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenv)
2. [conda](http://conda.pydata.org/miniconda.html)

The latter is my favorite and recommendation. It often works better, especially for installation of C extensions.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like only one `Python 2.7` copy. You can work with multiple Python without any issue if you can use `virtualenv`.